# Can't remove homepage slug in storyblok

Tags: storyblok

I have started to learn the storyblok CMS and I am stuck on a very basic problem already. I want to create a Home page (www.domain.com = no slug), but I can't get rid of the slug of my page. It is "home" by default, and this is what I get when I try to get rid of it:

[image]

And this is my structure:

[image]

I have also tried to create a new folder (let's say "Pages") with empty slug and set one of the pages there as a root, but it seems I have to give some slug at least to the folder, so the problem remains. Can't find anything about this problem and will be very thankful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty slug won't work because you need the slug for fetching the data **according to the storyblok support**. What you can do is fetch the data from specific slug in your application's home page.

Comment: That is correct – the reason is basically a proper REST API structure. Removing the slug will result into the endpoint for that one entry overriding `/stories/` which is the endpoint of loading multiple entries. If we would allow that you would not longer be able to load other entries. ;)

Comment: Thanks @DominikAngerer, seems like I wanted to make it work from the incorrect end of the problem. In the meantime I got in touch with storyblok much more and it's wonderful ;-)

Comment: Can you tell us what solution you used to workaround this? @ajobi

Comment: I can't remember exactly anymore but I think I simply made my `index` route fetch the `home` slug in the code, while other routes fetched based on the route slug still. Something like that probably :-)